# Best way to include CSS styles for mobile devices?

Tags: css, mobile-phones

Currently for a Web Application I have the structure of using a 
layout.css
layout_medium.css for tablet devices
layout_narrow.css for phone devices

Test A:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/project/assets/css/layout.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/project/assets/css/layout_medium.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 999px)" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/project/assets/css/layout_narrow.css media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
```

Test B
on layout.css I include the parts for

```
@import url('layout_medium.css') screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width:999px);
@import url('layout_narrow.css') screen and (max-width:480px);
```

Test B works on desktop for chrome and firefox but not on phones

Test A will always work, but then it clutters up my html head area which seems more dirty to me.

So the question is:
What is the Technical reason that Test B won't work on phones?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best background is this very good [quirksmode article series](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html) that explains viewports on mobile on how they're different than desktop. Read carefully!